# Python time duration comparison

Tags: python, datetime, time, comparison, timedelta

I am trying to compare two times within accuracy of a second, but i find some times the code calculates differently and my comparison does not work and the loop executes infinitely. I have pasted my code below, for reference

```
start_time = datetimenow() #datetimenow is a function which returns time w/o microseconds             
end_time =  start_time + timedelta(seconds = GrabDuration)
while datetimenow() != end_time: #this part fails sometimes and passes sometimes
    time.sleep(Grabtime)
    saveas(imggrab())
```

If you have any other better way of comparing time and time duration i would appreciate it if you could share.
GrabDuration & Grabtime is a user given variable for duration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `datetimenow` is returning a standard `datetime.datetime` object, so basically it's like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def datetimenow():
    return datetime.now()
```

Comparing `datetime` objects with `==` or `!=` makes it a bit tricky, because it takes a slight amount of time for them not be equal.

As a test just try these lines in a Python REPL (assuming the lines above are entered as well, so the `datetimenow()` function is available to call:

```
datetimenow() == datetimenow()
```

And it's quite possible among multiple tries, you'll get a few `False` results.

I'd suggest to compare the `datetime` objects with safer comparison operators, something like this:

```
while datetimenow() <= end_time:
    time.sleep(Grabtime)
    saveas(imggrab())
```

Comment: Thanks and yes the datetimenow() function returns a standard datetime.datetime object.

Its the While loop which gets tricky, i want the loop execute until the time gets equal. But what i found is the scenerio is not true all the time even though the end_time is derived from the datetimenow() plus user value.

The loop works as i intended for some of the runs but sometimes it executes till infinity. Basically all i want the loop to execute until the present time equal to the time specified by the user and it should be accurate to the seconds.

Comment: It is a common requirement to run a process, but make sure it won't take more than a given time. Using `<=` operator to compare the times instead of `==` answers such requirement. But in reality we don't have control over time (yet ;P). It's not clear to me how you'd like to process exactly for a given amount of time, specially if processing contains IO. When working with time values, it's safer not to use exact comparisons.

Comment: Hey Farzad, I found the solution. Its the sleep() function which gives out incorrect times sometimes. Instead of a passive time counter or wait function like sleep() if we replace by a active while loop which waits for each required seconds we will get a wait function which will give you exact time each time.

Comment: If that works for your application. just a reminder that an active while loop keeps the CPU busy.

Comment: Yes, I know that, thats why i tried to use the sleep() function but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import time
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds = GrabDuration)
while start_time != end_time:
    time.sleep(Grabtime)
```

if you have comparison between start time and end time, then this while loop of the code will execute infinite times only if start_time not equal to end_time

However the code you have shared, in that the while loop you are again taking the current system time and not using the strat_time variable for your comparison. Please check that.

You can also use datetime.datetime.now().time() method also like    datetime.datetime.now().time() < datetime.time(hour=2, minute=10, second=10). This may help you to solve your concerns.

Comment: thanks, your snippet had same problem, here is the print of the comparison. You can see the time skips a second to 3 sec even though the user input for Grabtime was 2 sec.
2016-03-23 15:49:50
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:49:53 # skipped to 3 sec 
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:49:55 # Good
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:49:57 # Good
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:49:59 # Good
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:50:02 # Bad 
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:50:04 #GOod
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52
2016-03-23 15:50:06 #Good
=
2016-03-23 15:49:52